# JPA: Automatically migrate from getter annotations to member annotations

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jpa, intellij-idea

We have several JPA/Hibernate entities with configuration annotations on the getter methods:

```
@Column(name = "CLOSING_POSITION_T234", nullable = false)
@NotNull
public BigDecimal getClosingPosition() {
    return closingPosition;
}
```

Instead we would like to have the annotations on the class members:

```
@Column(name = "CLOSING_POSITION_T234", nullable = false)
@NotNull
private BigDecimal closingPosition;
```

Is there a way to automatically migrate the annotations to the member variables with IntelliJ, Eclipse or NetBeans (or any other tool)?